# Azure IOT Message route query : array telemetry : Invalid Routing Condition

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

**Description:**
I want to place below query to filter telemetry data which should only to go to inbuilt Eventhub end point.

**My query:**
(NOT(IS_ARRAY($body)) OR ($body.length = 1 AND $body[0].type != 'Gateway' ) OR $body.length > 1)

**Query intent:**
Device telemetry data will be either array or single object. Most of my data will be one data object in array that is 'Gateway' type data. So i dont want to route that message to builtin end point since it is not required and i dont have control on device firmware not to send that telemetery.
If my telemetry array data object is having having more than one object then, i want to route to builtin end point.
If my telemetry data not array then also i need to route to builtin end point.
**Error Log:**
Invalid Routing Condition, RouteName:SensorsPayload, ErrorMessage:Message:Invalid operands to binary operator '!=': have 'undefined' and 'string', expected 'undefined' and 'undefined'.
**Test Data:**
**Data-1:**
{"timestamp":"2020-12-21T10:17:42.074Z","type":"Unknown","mac":"ACXXXXXXXXX3","bleName":"","rssi":-55,"rawData":"0201060303E1FF1016E1FFA10826F558263F23AC504C5553"}
**Data-2:**
[{"timestamp":"2020-12-21T10:17:42.074Z","type":"Gateway","mac":"ACXXXXXXXXX5","bleName":"","rssi":-55,"rawData":"0201060303E1FF1016E1FFA10826F558263F23AC504C5553"},{"timestamp":"2020-12-21T10:17:42.074Z","type":"Unknown","mac":"ACXXXXXXXXX3","bleName":"","rssi":-55,"rawData":"0201060303E1FF1016E1FFA10826F558263F23AC504C5553"}]
**Data-3:**
[{"timestamp":"2020-12-21T10:17:42.074Z","type":"Gateway","mac":"ACXXXXXXXXX5","bleName":"","rssi":-55,"rawData":"0201060303E1FF1016E1FFA10826F558263F23AC504C5553"}]

**Expected result for test data:**
Data-1: Should route to end point
Data-2: Should route to end point
Data-3: Should NOT route. it should be simply ignored.

Comment: It looks like, the IoT Hub message routing on the body is supported on the **JObject** only, such as your *Data-1* test sample. You can verified that using the simple routing query expression: *is_array($body)*, which it will not work.

Comment: @RomanKiss yes, is_array($body) is not working. In my case gateway device is not in my control, So how do i parse Data-2 or Data-3 in iot hub message routing?. Any help

Comment: There is no way to route the batch of telemetry data (array of messages) based on their data within the IoT Hub. You have to do it outside of the IoT Hub, for instance: in the stream consumer (azure stream analytics job) or iothubTrigger function.